# when i press my commit button is underlining da.update(ds, "Namtari") and it shows syntax error in INSERT IN statement. in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I press my commit button is underlining `da.update(ds, "Namtari")` and it shows syntax error in `INSERT` IN statement.

```
If inc <> -1 Then

Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Namtari").NewRow()

dsNewRow.Item("First_Name") = FirstName.Text
dsNewRow.Item("Second_name") = Surname.Text

ds.Tables("Namtari").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

**da.Update(ds, "Namtari")**

MessageBox.Show("New Record added to the Database")

btnCommit.Enabled = False
btnAddNew.Enabled = True
btnUpdate.Enabled = True>
btnDelete.Enabled = True

End If
```

Comment: Did you check to load the database and setting the current table into ds before updating?

Comment: What is the insert statement?